# Salesforce lightning on / off switch

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

I'd really like to use on / off toggle switches on my VF / lightning pages rather than a checkbox. Such as these used in the lightning setup pages

[image]

Are these available to developers as part of the lightning design framework, I can't see them listed?

Any examples would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to copy the html and css code from the salesforce page and implement your own component because there is no native / official  toggle/switch component from the lightning design system at the moment.

Alternatively you could take a [bootstrap switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) component.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I guessed. Seems strange they didn't include it since they clearly used it themselves.

Comment: @Neil Yep. Many of components are stil on the "beta" status, so I think we have to wait a bit till all of them will be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Try the checkbox toggle.  I think it was added fairly recently.

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/forms/#flavor-checkbox-toggle

Answer (score 1):

If you are using new Lightning web components or aura components you can have on/off switch by using lightning input component with type toggle

```
<lightning-input name="toggle" label="Toggle" type="toggle" message-toggle-active="toggle on" message-toggle-inactive="toggle off"> </lightning-input>
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input